# RxJS@6 fromFetch with catchError does not catching the errors

Tags: javascript, rxjs, fetch-api

I wanted to use the `fromFetch` method from RxJS in vanilla JS to improve pure `fetch` calls in legacy code.

It looks like this:

```js
fromFetch(`${requestUrl}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  },
  selector: (response) => response.json(),
}).pipe(
  catchError((err) => {
    // Do something with the error, then throw a custom error:
    return throwError('My Custom Error Message');
  }),
);
```

And in the place where I subscribe to this looks like:

```js
observable.subscribe({
  next: () => {},
  error: () => {
    // Handle errors
  },
});
```

After all these error handling, sometimes (I have no idea why), but error message appears on the screen:
[image]

How should I catch the error from the fetch? Maybe the error is coming from the `selector: (response) => response.json()` and I should move it out and handle the error there?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try putting a callback inside [`throwError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError) which will return an error class!

```
import './style.css';

import { catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { fromFetch } from 'rxjs/fetch';

// Open the console in the bottom right to see results.
fromFetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicoasdfasdfde.com/todos3/1`, {
  method: 'GET',
  selector: (response: any) => response.json(),
})
  .pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      // Do something with the error, then throw a custom error:
      return throwError(() => new Error('My Custom Error Message'));
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (asdf: any) => console.log('next', asdf),
    error: (error: any) => console.log('error', error.message),
  });
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-atphe8?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and I will get back to you.